# Gmapping can't run

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-jade, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all of ROS users,

I want to use the gmapping to get the X,Y location data and track path data I followed the the website as follows to install it:http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping

But when I type the command "rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=base_scan" in the terminal, it shows

[rospack] Error: package 'gmapping' not found

Does anyone knows how to solve it? Thank you very much for your kindly help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223051/gmapping-can%27t-run/) by [Terry Su](https://answers.ros.org/users/25230/terry-su/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2015-12-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i think the problem is ros is not able to find the gmapping package . So, first build the gmapping package into your ros workspace.

---

Originally posted by [sar1994](https://answers.ros.org/users/25409/sar1994/) with karma: 46 on 2015-12-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sar1994](https://answers.ros.org/users/25409/sar1994/) on 2015-12-24**:
or first check if it is available by the command $rospack find gmapping

**Comment by [Terry Su](https://answers.ros.org/users/25230/terry-su/) on 2015-12-24**:
I use the command $rospack find gmapping in the terminal, the error is same as"[rospack] Error: package 'gmapping' not found", but I really have installed it.

**Comment by [sar1994](https://answers.ros.org/users/25409/sar1994/) on 2015-12-24**:
where did u install the package. If its in your own workspace then source the setup.bash file

**Comment by [Terry Su](https://answers.ros.org/users/25230/terry-su/) on 2015-12-24**:
I installed the package in the "home" folder which is default, and I resource the setup.bash by this command $ source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash , but it is not working,too.

**Comment by [sar1994](https://answers.ros.org/users/25409/sar1994/) on 2015-12-24**:
here's the problem..
first of all the packages need to be built inside a ros workspace.. like /op/ros/indigo/share. This folder is the defualt workspace of ros. so u clone the git repo into the share folder and then build that . then u will be able to run the node.

**Comment by [Terry Su](https://answers.ros.org/users/25230/terry-su/) on 2015-12-25**:
I have changed the directory and use "git clone" to installed the file in the rosworkspace successfully.
But when I use the command "rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=base_scan", it shows "Couldn't find executable name slam_gmapping below /opt/ros/jade/share/slam_gmapping/gmapping"